# Visual Studio 2013 FTP Publish Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ftp, publish

I have a project that I built using VS 2010 and have published it a thousand times using VS 2010 with no problems.
I installed VS 2013 yesterday and loaded the project and it loaded fine.  I tried to publish it the way that I normally do (FTP) and I get several errors...
"Passive Mode" is checked in the "Publish Web Modal".  I have searched google and haven'nt found a solution.

My host is Godaddy.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here are a few of the errors that are viewable in the output tab....**

Publishing folder assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/patterns/white...

Publishing folder assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps...

Publishing folder assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps/js...

Unable to add 'assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps/js/colombiaLow.js' to the Web site.  The system cannot find the path specified (550).

Unable to add 'assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps/js/continentsHigh.js' to the Web site.  The system cannot find the path specified (550).

Publishing folder Views/Cloud_Readings...

Publishing folder Views/Cloud_Reminders...

Publish failed. Target ftp://abcd.com/workbackup.

Answer (score 0):

Feedback: I was never able to upload to Godaddy using VS2013/FTP. I had to create a new sub domain in Plesk on Godaddy's website. That took about 1 minute. I then was able to download the deployement file. I then uploaded the settings file into VS2013. I then was able to publish my MVC 4 application using the Web Deploy option.  It actually deploys a lot faster than VS2010 also. I hope this helps someone... [Here is a link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files)